# Content of /tmp is not visible from PHP-FPM when using Systemd

Tags: fedora, php, archlinux, systemd

Directory /tmp is not accessible from PHP-FPM running as Systemd service.

Steps to reproduce:

```
<?php
print_r(shell_exec('ls /tmp'));
?>
```

Answer (score 6):

This is default behaviour set by package maintainers.
It's because there is PrivateTmp=true in /usr/lib/systemd/system/php-fpm.service.

If you want to change it, you can create /etc/systemd/system/php-fpm.service.d/private-tmp.conf with contents:

[Service]
PrivateTmp=false