# File Exists in /tmp, but PHP returns "No such file or directory" on CentOS

Tags: php, centos

In PHP, I'm receiving this: `Warning: fopen(/tmp/mydir/file.txt): failed to open stream: No such file or directory` when calling `fopen ('/tmp/mydir/file.txt', "r");`

However:

```
cd /tmp
ls -l .
drwxrwxr-x 2 user  4.0K Aug 19 14:09 mydir
ls -l mydir
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user 41K Aug 19 14:09 file.txt
```

If I try to do `print_r(scandir('/tmp/'));` I get an empty array. Doing `print_r(scandir('/tmp/mydir/'));` I get `failed to open dir: No such file or directory`. However, doing `print_r(scandir('/home/user/'));` returns `failed to open dir: Permission denied`. For some reason, directories in `/tmp` show no such file or directory, even though they exist. It's also not a permission issue, and if it were, it would (should) produce the permission error.

What am I missing here? Or is this a known bug?

Comment: Are you using CentOS? It has a feature PrivateTmp=true that mounts /tmp and /var/tmp as visible only to that process. So every process sees a different virtual /tmp folder. See [Content of /tmp is not visible from PHP-FPM](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21615786/content-of-tmp-is-not-visible-from-php-fpm-when-using-systemd) for a possible solution.

Comment: @AndreaGhidini Yep. I never knew that existed. Could you put that as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It could be an issue with `PrivateTmp` feature: it mounts /tmp and /var/tmp as visible only to that process so every process sees a different virtual /tmp folder.

If you want to change it, you can create `/etc/systemd/system/php-fpm.service.d/private-tmp.conf` with contents:

```
[Service] PrivateTmp=false
```

Source for the fix: [Content of /tmp is not visible from PHP-FPM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21615786/content-of-tmp-is-not-visible-from-php-fpm-when-using-systemd)